# Apparently disconected concepts of Differential Geometry in basic Mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, geodesic, frenet-frame

**This questions is already answered in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367797/apparently-disconnected-concepts-of-differential-geometry-on-basic-mechanics/367807#367807[
But I would like more satifatoric answers. Please fell free to delete the question if this is an bad thing to do (posting duplicates)**

I) For this question I will use apparently disconnected concepts of vector calculus and differential geometry to illustrate my doubts. Moreover, I'll refer to [1]*FINN.E; Fundamental university physics Volume 1: Mechanics*   and to [2]*ANTON.H; Calculus: Multivariable*, in some results.

II) I'll need to be a little bit prolix in this question to explain my point

Consider velocity [1]:
\begin{equation}
 \vec{v} = \vec{r}\frac{dr(t)}{dt}+\vec{\theta}\frac{d\theta (t)}{dt}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
In the equation above we cleary see a particle under general curvilinear motion.
Which means that the terms :

$$\vec{r}\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$$ and $$\vec{\theta}\frac{d\theta (t)}{dt}$$

are respectively the radial velocity and tangencial velocity (where $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\theta}$ are simply the basis of polar coordinates).

If we consider $ \displaystyle \frac{dr(t)}{dt} = 0$ (the condition of time independent radius), then, equation (1) becomes:

$$  \vec{v} =\vec{\theta}\frac{d\theta (t)}{dt}\tag{2a} $$

and then the acceleration:
$$\vec{a} = -\vec{r}\left (\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}\right )^2 + \vec{\theta}\frac{d^{2} \theta(t)}{dt^{2}}\tag{2b}$$ 
This analysis is quite right, but [2] gives us another way to see the problem:

> *For a particle moving along a curve C in 2-space or 3-space,the velocity and acceleration vector can be written as:*
>
> $$ \vec{v} = \frac{ds(t)}{dt}\vec{T(t)}\tag{3a} $$
>   $$ \vec{a} = \frac{d^{2}s(t)}{dt^{2}}\vec{T(t)} + \kappa (t)\left (\frac{ds(t)}{dt}\right )^2 \vec{N(t)}\tag{3b} $$

Here the vectors $\vec{T(t)}$ and $\vec{N(t)}$ are precisely the vectors of TNB-triad (frenet trihedron), and $\kappa (t)$ is the Curvature.

Now, consider that we know the "general force":

$$ F^a = m\left( \frac{d^2x^a}{dt^2} + \Gamma^{a}_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{dt}\frac{dx^c}{dt} \right)\tag{4}$$

So, the Christoffel symbols vanish on Cartesian coordinates but in a curvilinear coordinate system, say polar coordinates, we can derive velocities and accelerations in the form of the set of equations 2.

**My first question is**: the set of equations 2 are the description of motion using a polar coordinate system. So, the set of equations 3 are independent of coordinate choice? And if so, why use polar coordinates then?

**My second question is**: How can we relate the equations 2, 3 and 4?